# Angular function with ng-if rendering figure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

In my showCtrl I have this

```
 $scope.showTeam = function(){
          var count = 0;
          for (var k in subordinates) {
              if (subordinates.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                  ++count;
              }
          }
          if(count > 0){
              return 1;
          }else{
              return 3;
          }
      }
```

I want to show figure div only if the function returns 1. So in my html I have this

```
<figure  ng-controller="ShowCtrl" ng-if="showTeam() === 1">
                //do something
</figure>
```

issue is that it renders figure for 1 and 3 both and I was expecting it to do it for 1 only. What am I missing here?

Comment: I pasted essentially your code into my controller and returned 1 in once instance and 3 in another, the directive worked properly.  Only showing for 1 and not for 3.

Comment: yes but the issue is that its not hidding or showing the <figure> depending on the returning value. For example I want it to hide <figure> is the returned value is not 1.

Comment: nevermind, find a way to do it. Will post my answer below

Comment: I see a problem with your code, but can't make a definitive answer without seeing your plunker. If you will.

Answer (score 0):

at a quick glance you should use `"showTeam() == 1"` and not `"showTeam() === 1"`. Are you getting javascript console errors?

Comment: I am not getting any js errors. And it wont matter if I use == or strict check ===

Comment: if that's the case, i don't think your angular app is even booting, you should see a javascript error. can you put your code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<figure  ng-controller="ShowCtrl" ng-show="showTeam() === 1">
                //do something
</figure>
```

ng-show was the way to do it I guess